# Huxreg() function with excluded coefficients using 'coef'

Tags: regression

I need help with doing a huxreg() regression table with 4 different models, but with the help of the 'coef' argument to only include two coefficients. Since two of the models use the LSDV approach, they have a lot of different coefficients which I would like to exclude, i.e. only including the two coefficients that all models have. How do I do this? To this point I have made the regression table like this:
huxreg(model_1, model_2, model_3, model 4, statistics = c(N = "nobs", R2 = "r.squared"), stars = c(`*` = 0.1, `**` = 0.05, `***` = 0.01)).